# leaflet no internet detection and notification

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, mapbox

If for example, my wifi goes offline, in leaflet i see new map areas grey but no notification about what really happening.

if i open the console i see:

```
GET https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/image.png?access_token=correct_token 
net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
```

anyone knows a way to catch such events and displaying a custom warning?

I already tried catching:

```
$scope.$watch('tileerror', function (error, tile) {
    alert("No coonection");
});
```

p.s. using angular-leaflet-directive

Comment: It's because the JS won't be notified at all that an error occurred when the error is due to no visibility on internet or cross domain issue, ... You could implement a ontileerror event based on a setTimeout method.

Comment: Probably related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33383092/leafletjs-check-for-not-loading-map/ but no out-of-the-box solution unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: as pointed out by Ghybs in the comments there is indeed a `tileerror` event firing from `L.TileLayer`, however as far as i can see it's not implemented in Angular Leaflet Directive, please correct me if i'm wrong.

L.TileLayer does have an option for setting a replacement image when the tile cannot be loaded called: `errorTileUrl`:

> URL to the tile image to show in place of the tile that failed to load.

```
new L.TileLayer(URL, {
    errorTileUrl: 'error.png'
});
```

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-errortileurl

If you need to preform some logic when tiles fail to load you could overwrite `L.TileLayer`'s `_tileOnError` method:

```
L.TileLayer.include({
    _tileOnError: function (done, tile, e) {

        // Do your stuff
        alert('whooops!');

        // Leaflet stuff
        var errorUrl = this.options.errorTileUrl;
        if (errorUrl) {
            tile.src = errorUrl;
        }
        done(e, tile);
    } 
});
```

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/tile/TileLayer.js#L96

Comment: Thank you!, Do you know how to overwrite tileOnError with angular-leaflet-directive? i want to try it and accept the answer but im using angular and dont have L.TileLayer

Comment: You have L.Tilelayer, the directive uses it internally. It's in the global scope as soon as leaflet.js is loaded. So include that piece of code after you load leaflet.js (anywhere, just as long as it's before you declare your map and you're good to go. When the directive initializes a L.Tilelayer it will call the modified version.

Comment: It is not advertised in Leaflet API, but there **is** a [`tileerror` event fired on Tile Layer](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/stable/src/layer/tile/TileLayer.js#L581) when it receives a 404 response: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/76/

Comment: Nice find, overlooked that one @ghybs. Undocumented go! :) I'll update my answer, thanks.

Comment: 404 errors won't trigger any handler on JS side if the error is GET https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/image.png?access_token=correct_token 
net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED, simply because it's not a 404 error. Some AJAX errors does not trigger anyhting os JS side

Comment: @StrandedKid, it's still an error and one can (as Leaflet does in L.Tilelayer) add a listener to the `img` element and catch the `error` event. `new Image().addEventListener('error', function() {});` What status doesn't matter.

Comment: @iH8 I've not tested but I think that if the error triggered by the browser is GET https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/image.png?access_token=correct_token 
net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED, new Image().addEventListener('error', function() {}); won't trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that the mechanism suggested by IH8 is very useful for stopping errors caused by broken or absent layer endponts.  The following modification to the pattern checks a single tile.  If there is an error, the offending layer is removed from the map, and a fallback (local) image `L.imageOverlay` is used.

```
var badtilecount = 0;
L.TileLayer.include({
    _tileOnError: function (done, tile, e) {

        // Do your stuff
        if (badtilecount == 0) {
        badtilecount += 1 
        alert('On-Line map not found at ' + esriUrl + 'Using local context map. ' + badtilecount);
        map.removeLayer(Esri_WorldTopoMap);
        map.addLayer(fallbackmap);
        }

        // Leaflet stuff
        var errorUrl = this.options.errorTileUrl;
        if (errorUrl) {
            tile.src = errorUrl;
        }
        done(e, tile);
    } 
});
```